# Cross-browser iOS like picker

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I wonder if there is a picker [Cross-browser] plugin for **JQuery** or other JavaScript frameworks. I've found some plugins like http://download.mobiscroll.com/, but they are based on **HTML5** and **CSS3**. There still users who use **Internet Explorer** to surf the web!

[image: something like this]

Comment: Something like city names

Comment: Interacting with something like that on a desktop browser that doesn't support touch gestures is horrible from a UI point of view. There's a good reason that Apple don't include that particular method in there Safari desktop browser. It was designed to make selection on touch devices easier. I'd suggest that unless it's a web app, use a normal HTML select input.

Comment: @benM I didn't mean it should support gestures, something with buttons to move through list.

Comment: Dont do it. Not only is it confusing and difficult to use on desktops, but it destroys the accessibility of your website. That and backwards support is only for that which is mission critical, like important design elements and content. If people are just picking citys as part of a form, just let them do it with native ui.

Comment: Obviously "there" should read "their" in my first comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there is no iOS picker for desktop and if there was, it was now a good Idea.